# Match may not be exhaustive warning is incorrect

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, compiler-warnings

So the scala compiler is complaining that a pattern match might not be exhaustive for the method `foo` and I wonder why. This is the code:

```
abstract class Foo {
    def foo(that: Foo): Unit = (this, that) match {
        case (Foo_1(), Foo_1()) => //case 1
        case (Foo_1(), Foo_2()) => //case 2
        case (Foo_2(), Foo_1()) => //case 3
        case (Foo_2(), Foo_2()) => //case 4
            // Compiler warning
    }

    def fooThis(): Unit = this match {
        case Foo_1() => //do something
        case Foo_2() => //do something
            // Works fine
    }

    def fooThat(that: Foo): Unit = that match {
        case Foo_1() => //do something
        case Foo_2() => //do something
            // Works fine
    }
}
case class Foo_1() extends Foo
case class Foo_2() extends Foo
```

And this is the error:

```
Warning:(5, 32) match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: (Foo(), _), (Foo_1(), _), (Foo_2(), _), (_, Foo()), (_, Foo_1()), (_, Foo_2()), (_, _)
    def foo(that: Foo): Unit = (this, that) match {
```

Since `this` and `that` are of type `Foo`, and `Foo` can only be of type `Foo_1` or `Foo_2`, the cases in `foo` are all possible combinations.

I added `fooThis` and `fooThat` for sake of completeness and to show that matching `Foo_1` and `Foo_2` suffices. The compiler message suggests that there are other types that can be matched (i.e. `Foo` and `_`).

**So why is this warning shown?**

Related:

- [Scala bug: fixed in 2.12.0-M4](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9630). My scala welcome message:

  > Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
- [Scala bug: false match not exhaustive warning on (unsealed, sealed) tuple](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9351)

---

**EDIT**

The compiler seems to complain as soon as you use tuples. If we add a dummy variable to `fooThis` as follows

```
def fooThis(): Unit = (this, Foo_1()) match {
    case (Foo_1(),_) => //do something
    case (Foo_2(),_) => //do something
}
```

we get the following compiler warning

```
Warning:(13, 27) match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: (_, _)
    def fooThis(): Unit = (this, Foo_1()) match {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Scala compiler won't give exhaustive match warnings for non-sealed traits (like your `Foo`). This explains why `fooThis` and `fooThat` compile without warnings.

If you want warnings here (and you should, because they're better than `MatchError` exceptions at runtime) you have a couple of options:

1. Make `Foo` sealed. This creates an [ADT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), which is safe to pattern match against in the sense that you'll get exhaustivity warnings when you forget a case. `Option` is an ADT that you're probably familiar with from the standard library. Here, you've already got cases for both `Foo_1` and `Foo_2`, so you won't get an exhaustivity warning. But if you ever forget either case, you will. You probably want to make `Foo_1` and `Foo_2` final while you're at it.
2. Leave `Foo` unsealed, use [Typelevel Scala](https://github.com/typelevel/scala/blob/typelevel-readme/notes/typelevel-4.md) and enable its `-Xlint:strict-unsealed-patmat` warnings.

On the other hand, the Scala compiler *will* give exhaustive match warnings for final case classes like `Tuple2`, which is what you're matching against in your `foo` method.

To answer "why is the warning shown?", consider what happens if we do this:

```
case class Foo3() extends Foo
val foo3 = Foo3()
foo3.foo(foo3)
```

(Answer: it throws a `MatchError` at runtime.)

The warning is the Scala compiler's way of helping you avoid the exception at runtime. If you want to make the warning go away, you could:

1. Make `Foo` sealed (again, creating an ADT), preventing `Foo3` from sneaking in elsewhere.
2. Add a wildcard `case _ => ...`.
3. Make the match unchecked: `((this, that): @unchecked) match { ...`.

Don't do number 3, because it leaves you vulnerable to `MatchError`s at runtime when someone introduces `Foo3`.

So, perhaps the question isn't really "why does the match in `foo` generate a warning", but "why **doesn't** the match in `fooThis` and `fooThat` generate a warning".

Comment: I indeed might have asked my question wrong and I would have rather asked the question of your last paragraph. Am I missing something or did you not answer it yourself in this answer? To me, the inconsistency bothered me, not the fact that the compiler generates a warning.

Comment: You're right, the inconsistency is jarring. The (unsatisfying) answer ultimately is that the Scala compiler just doesn't generate the exhaustivity warning for unsealed traits. You're not alone in wanting it to, as evidenced by the `strict-unsealed-patmat` compiler option in Typelevel's fork. Maybe we'll get `strict-unsealed-patmat` in some future version of Lightbend Scala. In the meantime I guess just be aware of it and stick to matching on ADTs.

Answer (score 2):

It seems making the abstract class sealed at least makes the compiler warning go away:

```
sealed abstract class Foo {
```

Though I'm not too sure why. It might be related to: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9351

Comment: Thanks for the info. Added the issue to the 'Related' list.

Comment: It's because sealing `Foo` precludes the existence of some hypothetical `Foo3` that also extends `Foo`, satisfying the compiler that the match is in fact exhaustive.

Answer (score 0):

Figuring out all subclasses of a class is called Class Hierarchy Analysis, and doing static CHA in a language with dynamic code loading is equivalent to solving the **Halting Problem**.

Plus, one of the goals of Scala is separate compilation and deployment of independent modules, so the compiler simply cannot know whether or not a class is subclassed in another module, because it never looks at more than one module. (After all, you could compile a module against the interface of some other module without that module even existing on your system!) **That's why sealed requires all subclasses to be defined in the same compilation unit**.
That's why the compiler doesn't show warnings, because its aware of the existing subclasses.